# Android Map of ENUM and Function

Tags: android, function, enums

I am trying to implement a Map object that would have for key an ENUM, and for value, a function to call. The equivalent of a function pointer for c++.

All the functions of the Map have the same prototype.

Is there a way to do it with Android ?

I don't have code to provide since i'm always working on the architecture of my app.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Since functions in Java on Android are not first class, you can't do precisely what you describe.  That said, you can store in your Map a reference to an object that implements the `Interface` you wish it to adhere to.  That way, once you have a reference to the object, you can call the interface method that is implemented by the object.